# TB: "There was an error attaching fetch>UID>^[Gmail]^Drafts>122656."

Tags: images, thunderbird

A draft message "There was an error attaching fetch>UID>^[Gmail]^Drafts>122656" came up when attempting to send one message.  All other messages went out fine.  Thunderbird just hiccuped on one draft.  Several previous attempts to send this particular message seemed to be successful but the message never made it to the Sent box.

I am using gmail as my provider, with IMAP.  TB version 38.6.0.

I was able to retrieve the draft from the gmail drafts folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hint at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=515143 (from 2007!).

I deleted a phantom image in the message I was replying to.  Then I didn't get the error message.  However, the message still didn't make it into my Sent folder.

What I finally did was to start a new message with just my new text, omitting the message I was replying to.  *That worked.*